# Show a mod menu on questions summaries

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

[A recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions) revealed a need for a quick way to moderate many questions from their summaries.

What is a question summary?  Its the view of a question within a list, such as the front page or search results:

[image]

(Its referred to as a summary in the html, not sure if that is the common name)

#### Anyhow...

As it currently stands, a moderator cannot act within this view.  The mod must first open the question in order to access the mod menu, or get to the Close/Delete links.

When you're talking about a question here/there, its not too much of a problem.  When you're talking about *fifteen thousand questions*, son, we have issues.

I'd suggest adding an abbreviated list of links under the tags on the summary:

[image]

so that we can hit and run without opening 15k tabs.

Comment: _pities SO moderators_

Comment: Closing questions without even reading them? Me likes!

Comment: @YannisRizos: You don't have to open the flaming paper bag on your front porch to figure out whether you should or shouldn't stomp it out.

Comment: It gets boring when there aren't that many flags to process.  Time for *real* moderating to begin!

Comment: @Won't No, I mean it, I like it and it will be extremely useful in massive cleanups. But if this gets build, MSO will fill with "I'm sure they closed it from the summary, didn't even bother to read it" crap...

Comment: @YannisRizos: To which I say, "Yes!  I did!  HAHAHAHAAHAH!  SUCKET!"

Answer (score 10):

Can't think of a good reason for this, honestly. The moderator flag queue is already set up to where you can close or delete a question based on the summary and flag, with the assumption being that *someone* looked at the whole thing and you need only do so again if something seems fishy about it.

A system where stuff gets closed or deleted without *anyone* looking at it is... Dangerous.

Comment: Why, [here's a good reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions).  And if you trust us, then you should trust us to use this wisely.  For those rare occasions where someone starts out their totally legit question "You want handbag? Cheap and fast shipping. High quality." they can flag and ask for a review.

Comment: I trust you to make good decisions. Therefore, depriving you of the information you need to make those decisions is counter-productive. Also... Read my answer to that question. Have you actually *looked* at those queries? Past the first page of results?

Comment: WANT TO DELETE EVERYTHING.  NOW.

Comment: We're supposed to *look* at that stuff now?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions), the question do need review first. If the question+answers are good, leave open (+edit if necessary)... If not, close.

Questions can be about:

1. Concept in specific books
2. Concept about specific tools
3. Recommendation of any good method, concept in book/about tool
4. Comparison between tools
5. Comparison between concepts in different books

So we need to read those questions. And required to take actions. Thats why I said 70% question will get closed an not 100%.

If without reading questions are getting closed then we will miss many more questions. And 95% times if question get closed as Not Constructive then people even don't think of reopening it.

Comment: If it is so incredibly obvious from the summary, why bother?  The question is already bad, therefore it gets closed.  If there is a suggestion of value, then you open it up.  Its honestly not rocket science.

Comment: But it will not case for all questions other than recommendation question. And all recommendation questions will not be about books and tools.

Comment: Do you think, once given this tool, mods will become ignorant link clickers?  "Oh, look, there is a delete link in the summary!  I must click it without any thought!"  The idea is foolish.  Nothing has changed on the part of moderators.  The only thing that has changed is that we don't have to waste time closing obvious crap.

Comment: I don't think moderators are ignorant link clickers.